# How do you put two TextViews next to each other in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am a beginner in Android Studios, and my TextViews will not be placed next to each other, instead one is on top of the other. I am really confused about what I did wrong.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="@string/already_registered"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ECAB71"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` tag closed too early. Use `>` instead of `/>` in your `LinearLayout` element.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Already registered"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ECAB71"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the backslash in line 5

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="@string/already_registered"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ECAB71"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```